# understanding some concepts in java generics

Tags: java, generics

So I came across this code while studying linkedlists. The code here uses generics and I am having problem understanding some of the things here.

```
public static class Node<E> 
{
     E element;
     Node <E> next;
    public Node(E e,Node <E> n)
    {
        element=e;
        next=n;System.out.println(next);
    }
    public E getelement() {return element;}
    public Node<E> getnext(){ return next;}
    public void setnext(Node <E> n)
    {
        next=n;
    }
}
```

So what does class Node `<E>` mean?
I think E element; means  element is of type E. Am I right?
Node `<E>` next; what does this mean?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Yes, you're right: `E element` declares a field named `element`, of type `E`. `Node<E> next` declares a field name `next`, of type `Node<E>`. A linked list, by definition, contains nodes linking to the next one, to form... a linked list.

Comment: Node next would mean an object of class next;Does Node`<E>` next mean that next is an object of class Node`<E>`?

Comment: I just told you: `Node<E> next` declares a field named `next`, of type `Node<E>`. DOn't know how I could be clearer. Just like in any Java variable declaration, the type comes first (Node<E>), and the name comes after (next). When you declare a variable `int i`, `int` is the type, and `i`is the name. Same thing here.

Comment: Ah! got it. Btw what does `<E>` beside the class name mean?

Comment: A List<String> is a list containing elements of type String. Is that understood? So a List<E> is a list containing elements of type E. A linked list is made of nodes. A Node<E> is a node containing an element of type E. When linked together, they form a List<E>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<E>` by the class name declares that `E` as a generic type parameter - this means any instance of `Node` will be of some type, and this type will be decided by the code that instantiates it.  `new Node<String>()` will create a node of type String, `new Node<Integer>()` creates a node of type Integer, and so on.

Where `E` is used in the class then reflects whatever type a particular instance has chosen, so if a have a node of type String, I know that `element` will be a String, and `next` will be a reference to another node containing a String.

The beauty of generics is that using this type parameter means I don't need to write a copy of this class for each type I want to use, while also being sure that all of the references will be of the type I expect - I won't get `next` returning an Integer when I'm expecting a String.

The [link JB Nizet provides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) is a very good one - generics are quite a large and subtle topic, and if you wnat to learn about generics that tutorial will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and many other resources for such a big topic in Java, I'll try to explain it by "the process of re-creating generics".

Say you're going to implement the class `Node` given in the question, it's a basic building unit for LinkedList, so you define it as:

```
class Node {
    private Node next;

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

but you need to store some data in each `Node`, don't you, otherwise this class is useless. Obviously one more field is necessary and the type you want to store is `MyData`, then it'll be:

```
class Node {
    private MyData element;
    private Node next;

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public MyData getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(MyData element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

One day you want to make your implementation a common library so it can be used by anyone, but one serious problem comes up which is people will not happy with that they can only store data of type `MyData` in your `Node`, they want to store whatever type they want, so you made a little change - declare the type of `element` to `Object` so that it can handle any type:

```
class Node {
    private Object element;
    private Node next;

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Object getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(Object element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Everything's good now, but some time later you receive some feedbacks from some picky users:

- User A: everywhere I call `Node.getElement()` in my code, I get an `Object` type stuff and I need to do a type cast, which is inconvenient, it would be better if what I get from `getElement` is the type I want
- User B: I want to only store type `A` but there's no way to prevent me put a type `B` into `Node`, I can't find this bug till exception happens during runtime, it would be better that compiler can help me to find the bug

So you feel that it'll be great if you can leave the decision of what `type` of data is allowed to put in `Node` to users, rather than hardcoded in implementation, which means what you'll put at the underscore of the statement `private ___ element;` is uncertain, you need it be a variable and specified by the user at the moment they use it, so **a variable to the class**, that's good, but you need a place to **declare the variable before you can use it**, finally you decide to put the declaration of the variable right after the class name, inside `<>`(a new syntax), then the code will be:

```
class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node next;

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

almost done but wait: you're using `Node` by yourself - the field `next`, you need to follow the rule you just made: *pass type info of element to `Node` at the time when you use it*, so finally you got the code following:

```
class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Em....Sorry I didn't expect this to be so long...But hope it could be a little helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I always learn best from example, so put `Node` to a simple use:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class TestNode{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //assume you have 3 points
        Point point1 = new Point(40,40);
        Point point2 = new Point(80,120);
        Point point3 = new Point(70,200);

        //each point is connected to one other point. to represent such connection you
        //can create a Node<Point> or in other words Node of Point.
        //define the last node in the chain, which has no next node:
        Node<Point> node3 = new Node<>(point3, null);
        //Note: because Node<E> is generic you could define Node<Cats>, Node<Dogs>, Node<AnyType>

        //define the point2-point3 connection
        Node<Point> node2 = new Node<>(point2, node3);
        //define point1-point2 connection
        Node<Point> node1 = new Node<>(point1, node2);

        //now put it to test. node1.getnext() return node2, node1.getnext().getelement() returns point2
        System.out.println("Point 2 x-y " +node1.getnext().getelement().getX()
                                                              +"-"+node1.getnext().getelement().getY());

        //now put it to test. node1.getnext().getnext() return node3
        System.out.println("Point 3 x-y " +node1.getnext().getnext().getelement().getX()
                                                    +"-"+node1.getnext().getnext().getelement().getY());
    }
}
```